# SQLITE Database for Windows Phone 8.1(Silverlight)

Tags: sqlite, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app for windows phone 8.1 using SilverLight in that I am storing details of some products using sqlite but I want to know how can I store that data permanently means when I close the emulator the data is lost. So please let me know how do I store that data.

Comment: You can use tools like "Windows Phone Power Tools" to retrieve the DB file(s) before closing it. Indeed, you can restore the file(s) back the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you close the emulator, all the data is lost and all the apps deleted. Imagine it as doing a hard reset on your device.

Your only solution is not to close the emulator or get a real device for testing.

Comment: Exactly!! the answer