# Save data permanently in SQLite on UWP

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I installed SQLite for UWP fine and it´s works well.

```
[PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
    conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(),path);
    conn.CreateTable<Message>();

var add = conn.Insert(new Customer() { Name = textBox.Text });
```

I launch emulator, insert something to textbox, add with button and with other button I can show, what I write there. But when I shutdwon simulator and relaunch app, click on Show button, there is nothing. So data save to database only to the shutdown. But I need these data after shutdown too. How save the data permanently?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLITE Database for Windows Phone 8.1(Silverlight)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037875/sqlite-database-for-windows-phone-8-1silverlight)

Comment: Are you running the app in the phone emulator or the simulator? The emulator is hard reset on every start, so this behavior is expected. The simulator on the other hand shares the state with your computer, therefore such behavior would be unexpected.

Comment: thanks to know, it´s the problem, because every time i try it on emulator.